# What was the originator of the SEE! ... SEE! ... lines on movie posters?

Tags: cinema-history, posters

A fair number of older movie posters, tending around the late 60's and early 70's, have commands on the side of the poster starting with SEE! and then some kind of generic or interesting event supposedly in the film. For examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So far as I can tell, based on the three examples alone, I can't find a single director or producer in common between them.

I was wondering if there was any specific poster manufacturer or movie that started this trend, or if there was some historic significance to this advertising method.

Comment: It's not specific to movies...circus posters were doing that before movies were invented....it's ancient.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps it had something to do with the fact that motion pictures were still a relatively new thing in the early-to-mid part of the 20th century, so any type of story (aside from reading) could only be heard on the radio. So emphasizing the fact that you could "SEE" the action was a big selling point.  Although, your question says "60's to 70's" era, so perhaps I'm off base.

Comment: As a note, this was commonly done in the previews as well. I'll see if I can find some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a movie program from 1926 that promotes *THE ANCIENT HIGHWAY* (1925).

[image]

The text says:

> SEE -- the dynamite blast free the log jam; the thrilling rescue
>   during the explosion; the battle between the lumberjacks; the giant
>   tree crash on the lumber camp.

Another example from 1926, an advertising herald from *[THE FLAMING FRONTIER](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0016881/)* (1926)

[image]

> SEE The Indians on the Warpath
>
> A Beautiful and Romantic Love Story
>
> The Dare-devil Rough Riding
>
> The Emigrant Trail
>
> The Drama of Political Intrigue

So this style of ballyhoo has been going on a long time...